# Find bugs does not show up when right clicking project or file in Eclipse

Tags: java, junit, eclipse-plugin, findbugs

I have Eclipse 4.2.1, and I just downloaded find bug.  It shows up in show view and marketplace says that it installed, however when I right click on an entire project or an individual Junit test case the option isn't there.  I looked in the find bug preferences and didn't see anything that would help.  Any ideas what's going on?  Can I still use it without right click? (I am trying to follow a tutorial and I am stuck on the right click step)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if anyone will ever encounter this as I did, but just in case it may help someone I'll answer this question.

Problem turned out to be with the project I was working on, for some reason when I checked out with svn it was not downloaded as a java project, therefore find bugs did not work on it.  I checked out the project again, and it checked out normally as a java project and I had no problems